# Unwanted space above pictures in table cells

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and have a question about placing external graphics in table cells and align them correctly. Yes, I did read a similar posts but couldn't find the solution to my problem yet.

Here is my code (Please notice my usage of the Ti*k*Z. That is because I later want do draw arrows on top of my table.):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,fadings,matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{title}
\begin{tikzpicture}[,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,on grid,x=.001\linewidth,y=.001\linewidth]
\node (tab) at (0,0) [align=center,anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] %I used TikZ because I want to draw on top of my table but the usage of TikZ is not the cause of my problem.
{
\begin{tabular}{r>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{text text }&\multicolumn{2}{c}{text text text }\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}
&&A &B\\
\midrule
1&text text text text text &The pictures should be placed like this paragraph here but they have some unwanted space above them.&\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter}}\\ %I've read about the \raisebox but that doesn't seem to help.
\midrule
&&caption A1, a caption with more than one row&caption B1\\
\midrule
2&In this table row the pictures are placed correctly but this text isn't. &\includegraphics[width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter}    &\includegraphics[width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter}\\ %Without the \raisebox the pictures are top-aligned but the text at the beginning of the row isn't.
\midrule
&&caption A2    &caption B2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
};
\begin{scope}[opacity=.75,transparency group]%just an example for what I want to do with TikZ
\draw[->,red,very thick] (500,10) to node[sloped, anchor=center, above] {This arrow is just an TikZ-example...} (800,350);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get:
[image: output]

I want to place external images in my table cells but if I do so, there is unwanted space above them (row 1 in the table) or the text-filled cells behave weird (row 2). How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Where is that similar post? Could you link to it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the package `adjustbox` here. Please note the option `valign=t` I added to each image:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % you can remove this.
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e,microtype,lmodern} % some tweaks to get it really nice

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,on grid,x=.001\linewidth,y=.001\linewidth]
        \node (tab) at (0,0) [align=center,anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
        {
            \begin{tabular}{%
                r
                >{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}
                *2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
                }
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{text text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text text text} \\
            \cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}
            & & A & B \\
            \midrule
            1 & text text text text text & The pictures should be placed like this paragraph! Check & \includegraphics[valign=t,width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter} \\
            \midrule
            & & caption A1, a caption with more than one row & caption B1 \\
            \midrule
            2 & In this table row the pictures are placed correctly. So is the text. & \includegraphics[valign=t,width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter} & \includegraphics[valign=t,width=4cm]{../Grafiken/Platzhalter} \\ 
            \midrule
            & & caption A2 & caption B2 \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        };
        \begin{scope}[opacity=.75,transparency group]
        \draw[->,red,very thick] (500,10) to node[sloped, anchor=center, above] {This arrow is just a Ti\textit{k}Z-example\dots} (890,200);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]